# Unable to select section tag

Tags: python, scrapy

I am unable to select any `section` tag and all tags that are inside one. My goal is to **scrape** information contained in the `section` tags.

```
response.xpath("//section")
```

will return `[]`

This is the link:
https://www.pararius.com/frontend/en/listing-points-of-interest/5.13689124/52.08889907

Comment: The xpath expression is correct. Does `response` contain what you expect it to contain? Are you sure the server is not returning a 403 when you fetch the page with your script?

Comment: view(response) return the same as the website. I run the expression in shell. How can I get Debug code?

Comment: are you sure the page contains sections? I don't see any in its source code

Comment: yes, if you inspect "Tram" it in section tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the page is java script rendered. Scrapy can't run java script but splash can: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash